# Does every continuous map from $\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$ to itself have a fixed point?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

This question is motivated by [Fixed point property of Cayley plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100413/fixed-point-property-of-cayley-plane/) and idle curiosity.

In the link, it is shown that every continuous map from the Cayley plane to itself has a fixed point and the argument (with easy modification) applies equally well to $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$, $\mathbb{C}P^{2n}$ and $\mathbb{H}P^{2n}$.

The leaves open the case of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$, $\mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}$, and $\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$.

In the case $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$, this space covers many the lens spaces, so in particular (via the Deck group), admits many fixed point free self maps (diffeomorphisms, in fact).

In the case $\mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}$, the Lefschetz theorem shows that any continuous map without fixed points must act as $-1$ in $H^2$, and indeed, there is a such a map $(\mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}$ double covers a nonorientable manifold).  So again, there is a diffeomorphism with no fixed points.

This leaves open the case of $\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$.  The same argument as in the previous case shows that $f$ must act as $-1$ in $H^4$.  This certainly can be achieved when $n=0$.  In this case, $\mathbb{H}P^1 = S^4$ and the antipodal map is a diffeomorphism which acts without fixed points.

However, for $n > 0$, there is no such diffeomorphism.  This comes from the fact that the first Pontrjagin class is a diffeomorphism invariant and is a nonzero multiple of the generator of $H^4(\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1})$.  This implies that any diffeomorphism must act as $+1$ on $H^4$.  I think Novikov's result on the rational invariance of Pontrjagin classes under homeomorphisms gives us the same result for homeomorphisms.

Thus, if there is a map $f:\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$ without fixed points, it cannot be a homeomorphism.  Hence my question:

> Is there a continuous function $f:\mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}P^{2n+1}$ without fixed points when $n > 0$?  Is there an example where $f$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any map $\mathbb{HP}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{HP}^n$ must have a fixed point for $n >1$. This is discussed on page 493 of [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html). It follows from some calculations and use of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.

Comment: Nice - thanks for the reference!  It also motivates me to learn Steenrod powers finally.

Comment: The Steenrod operations are tremendously useful, and there's a lot to learn. It's nice what you can prove just knowing the axiomatic properties that define them.

Comment: I've studied Steenrod squares a bit - even they are enough to prove a ton of stuff, but I've never really looked at Steenrod powers for general $p$ at all.